# How can I automatically escape HTML content using Jekyll and Markdown?

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

In foo.markdown I have the following:

```
---
layout: default
title: Snarky little Ewok
---

A little Ewok is sometimes referred too as <h3>. But pappa Ewok is called <h1> - if you know what's good for you.
```

Well, I want Jekyll to automatically html escape the greater than and less than characters. I'm seriously fatigued after today's apprentice training and I'm just too lazy to manually html escape myself: >h3<

Is there a config option or something to automatically escape Jekyll markdown content?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you used textile instead of markdown, there would be a way.

Liquid markup has [textilize & escape](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) filters; those two would allow you to do what you wanted, but on textile. You would have to save your files as text (file extension: txt), and then escape the html before textilizing:

```
---
layout: default
title: Snarky little Ewok
---

This file's extension is .txt

A little Ewok is sometimes referred too as <h3>. But pappa Ewok is called <h1> - if you know what's good for you.
```

Then on the default.html layout, instead of having:

```
{{ page.content }}
```

You would have this:

```
{{ page.content | xml_escape | textilize }}
```

Since there's no 'markdownify' filter on Jekyll yet, you can't do that with markdown. There's an issue ([Issue 134](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issuesearch?state=open&q=markdownifi#issue/134)) on Jekyll for adding a markdownify filter.

EDIT:

It's now possible to use markdown (since jekyll 0.10.1)

```
{{ page.content | xml_escape | markdownify }}
```

Comment: In this one strong it is the force.

Comment: No, it's `{{ page.content | markdownify }}`  -- [Liquid Extensions](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions)

Comment: Since 2011 `escape` has been renamed to `xml_escape`. I can't provide an example here, please open a new question if you are still interested.

Comment: If you just want to remove html tags in Jekyll consider using the `strip_html` filter.